# how to pass time Interval in list pref option

Tags: android, handler, android-preferences

```
<ListPreference
 android:entries="@array/listOptions2"
 android:entryValues="@array/listValues2"
 android:key="listprefrefresh"
 android:summary="Set refresh the Application"
 android:title="Set Time Interval" />
```

```
    <item>10 </item>
    <item>30</item>

</integer-array>
<integer-array name="listValues2">
    <item>10000</item>
    <item>30000</item>
</integer-array>
```

This is my code i want Pass Time how can i implement right now? I am passing Integer value.please tell me

```
public static final String PREF_BEER_SIZE2 = "listprefrefresh";
        Preference beerPref2 = (Preference) findPreference(PREF_BEER_SIZE2);
    beerPref2
                    .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                Object newValue) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            final ListPreference listrefresh = (ListPreference) preference;
                            final int idx = listrefresh
                                    .findIndexOfValue((String) newValue);

                            if (idx == 0 ) {
                                handler.post(timedTask);

                                //


                            } else if (idx == 1) {
                                // System.out.println("2");

                            } 
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```